# Find max and min within matching array in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an object like below...

```
var SpecialObj=
{   
    "dataarray-345":
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
        {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
        {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"}
    ],
    "dataarray-123":
    [

        {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
        {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
        {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
        {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"},
        {lqd: 2500, date: "2017-08-18 12:00:00"},
        {lqd: 3500, date: "2017-08-18 12:30:00"}
    ],
    "dataarray-127":
    [
        {lqd: 8500, date: "2017-08-18 13:00:00"},
        {lqd: 9500, date: "2017-08-18 13:30:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ]
}
```

Now I need to check individual array if the 1st **or** last index are with other other array or not if yes then need to fiend the max and min. if no then need to fiend that particular array max and min separately. For above object below should be my output...

```
{   
    "dataarray-345":
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 3500, date: "2017-08-18 12:30:00"}
    ],
    "dataarray-123":
    [
        {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
        {lqd: 3500, date: "2017-08-18 12:30:00"}
    ],
    "dataarray-127":
    [
        {lqd: 8500, date: "2017-08-18 13:00:00"},
        {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
    ]
}
```

is it possible in javascript? What could be the way in javascript? Can you help me please?

Comment: I don't understand how you are supposed to get that output from the given input. Can you elaborate on what algoritm is usend to determine that output?

Comment: dataarray-123 0th date is in  dataarray-345 array so i need to fiend the max and min of those two but dataarray-127 array 1st and last are not between any other array so its max and min should fiend from dataarray-127 array itself.

Comment: Any help from any one? is it possible in any way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a little rough around the edges, don't have time to add comments and optimize, but it works.

The log of the snippet is a little odd but when you open your dev tools you will see the expected output.

```js
const 
  SpecialObj = {   
      "dataarray-345":
      [
          {lqd: 1000, date: "2017-08-18 09:30:00"},
          {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
          {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
          {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
          {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"}
      ],
      "dataarray-123":
      [

          {lqd: 5000, date: "2017-08-18 10:00:00"},
          {lqd: 5500, date: "2017-08-18 10:30:00"},
          {lqd: 4500, date: "2017-08-18 11:00:00"},
          {lqd: 1500, date: "2017-08-18 11:30:00"},
          {lqd: 2500, date: "2017-08-18 12:00:00"},
          {lqd: 3500, date: "2017-08-18 12:30:00"}
      ],
      "dataarray-127":
      [
          {lqd: 8500, date: "2017-08-18 13:00:00"},
          {lqd: 9500, date: "2017-08-18 13:30:00"},
          {lqd: 6500, date: "2017-08-18 14:00:00"}
      ]
  };
  
/**
 * Creates a reverse lookup object. For each unique lqd value it will list the 
 * keys that contain the lqd value.
 *
 * @param {Object} input  The input object to create a reverse lookup for.
 *
 * @returns {Object} An object where each unique lqd value is a property with 
 *          it's value an array of object keys.
 */
function getReverseLookupObject(input) {
  // Create the result object.
  const
    result = Object.create(null);
    
  // Iterate over the object properties.
  for (let key in input) {
    // When the current property is from the prototype chain we will skip it.
    if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    // Iterate over all the items in the array that is stored under the property.
    input[key].forEach(item => {
      // Check if the current lqd is not yet in the result.
      if (result[item.lqd] === undefined) {
        // Create a property for the lqd value and assign it an array with the current key.
        result[item.lqd] = [key];
      } else {
        // Add the current key to the array.
        result[item.lqd].push(key);
      }
    });
  }
  
  // Return the reverse lookup object.
  return result;
}

/**
 * Returns an array with two items. The item at index 0 will be the item with the 
 * earliest date. Index 1 will contain the item with the latest date.
 *
 * @param {Array} array  The array with source items.
 *
 * @returns {Array} An array with the items that have the earliest and latest date.
 */
function getMinMax(array) {
  // Sort the source array by date property, ascending.
  array.sort((a, b) => new Date(a.date).getTime() - new Date(b.date).getTime());
  
  // Return an array with the first and last item in the sorted array.
  return [
    array[0],
    array[array.length - 1]
  ]
}

/**
 * Returns a set of properties in the original input object that contain the
 * lqd of either the first or last item in the array.
 */
function getParentKeys(reverseLookupObject, keyValues) {
  const
    // Get last index if the keyValue array.
    lastIndex = keyValues.length - 1,
    // Get the array with keys that contain the lqd for the 1st item.
    firstElementParents = reverseLookupObject[keyValues[0].lqd],
    // Get the array with keys that contain the lqd for the last item.    
    lastElementParents = reverseLookupObject[keyValues[lastIndex].lqd];
    
  // Create a set of the keys. This has the benefit that duplicate keys will
  // be removed. When the first and last element both have the same parent the
  // resulting set will only contain that parent once.
  return new Set([...firstElementParents, ...lastElementParents]);
}

function transformData(input) {
  const
    // Create the reverse lookup object.
    reverseLookup = getReverseLookupObject(input),
    // Initialize the result.
    result = Object.create(null);
  
  // Iterate over the properties of the input object.
  for (let key in input) {
    // When the property if from the prototype chain we can skip it.
    if (!input.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      continue;
    }
    
    const
      // Get the input object properties that contain the lqd of the first and last items.
      parentKeys = getParentKeys(reverseLookup, input[key]);
    let
      combinedItems = [];
    // Iterate over the parents and combine all their values into a single array.
    parentKeys.forEach(parentKey => combinedItems = [...combinedItems, ...input[parentKey]]);
    
    // Add the current key in the result with the items that have the earliest and 
    // latest date.
    result[key] = getMinMax(combinedItems);
  }
  return result;
}

console.log(transformData(SpecialObj));
```

Comment: Hi @Thijs is it possible to write in plane Javascript because my application is not accepting for ES6 pattern code. Thank you

Comment: Can you use lodash? That would be the easiest way to transition this answer from ES6 to ES5 code.